# GWT History onValueChange() not being called

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-history

I have a method in a class that implements `ValueChangeHandler<String>` this class is initialised from within the `onModuleLoad()` method like so

```
mainController = new MainController();
History.addValueChangeHandler(mainController);
mainController.initialise(History.getToken());
```

And the `initialise()` method looks like this;

```
public void initialise(String initialToken) {
    if (initialToken.equals("")) {
        History.newItem(String.valueOf(HistoryTokens.MAIN_PAGE), true);
    } else {
        History.newItem(initialToken, true);
    }
}
```

When the app is started with a blank history token, ie when *Launch Default Browser* is pressed then the `onValueChange()` method is called, changing the url whilst the app is running calls the `onValueChange()` method.

However, entering a URL in a blank browser tab with a token in the URL, ie `http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyApp.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#mjh&jdfhfh=786543`, does not call the `onValueChange()` method. I'm confused as I hit the `History.newItem(initialToken, true);` part of the `if` statement. I thought that this would ensure that `onValueChange()` was called. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always call the `History.fireCurrentHistoryState()` at the end of your GWT onModuleLoad(). I think that should solve your problem.

The thing is that the first history event ( like when you load page.com/#xyz ) is not captured by the ValueChangeHandler, you have to "fake it" with the `History.fireCurrentHistoryState()`

Comment: More accurately: unless the token is empty, `newItem` is called with current token: the token doesn't change, so there's no `ValueChangeEvent`. Case made.

Comment: This doesn't entirely answer my question but using the method you suggest did solve the problem. I tried to engineer a solution using my initialise() method but the fireCurrentHistoryState() method works better. Thanks.